# OpenCV get faces from image and predict with model

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

The piece of code which retrieves faces from grayscale image (already converted to cv::Mat) works oddly,
what I'm doing wrong?

```
// in initializer list 
model(cv::face::FisherFaceRecognizer::create())
// ....
const cv::Mat grayscale = cv::imread("photo_15.jpeg",cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

std::vector<cv::Rect> faceCandidates;
m_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale, faceCandidates);

uint32 label = -1;         
double confidence = 0.0;
// this line for the testing purposes only
model->predict(grayscale, label, confidence);
```

this works fine : label refers to correct person and confidence within 10. 
but lets continue with this function code:

```
for (auto &faceCandidateRegion : faceCandidates) {
    cv::Mat faceResized;
    // size_ is a member and contains 1280x720 for my case, equal to model trained photos. 
    cv::resize( cv::Mat(grayscale, faceCandidateRegion), faceResized, cv::Size(size_.width(), size_.height()));

    // Recognize current face.
    m_model->predict(faceResized, label, confidence);
// ... other processing
```

this piece of code works absolutely wrong: it always produces incorrect label and confidence is about ~45-46K even if I use a recognition  photo from training photo set

any idea what I'm doing wrong here? 
for the testing : I've tried to perform this with fisher, eigen and lbph with the same wrong result

update: each model in the app is a few user's group, where each user presented by  2-6 photos , so this is a reason why I train a few users in the model

here is a code which trains the models:

```
std::size_t
Recognizer::extractFacesAndConvertGrayscale(const QByteArray &rgb888, std::vector<cv::Mat> &faces)
{
    cv::Mat frame = cv::imdecode(std::vector<char>{rgb888.cbegin(), rgb888.cend()}, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    std::vector<cv::Rect> faceCandidates;
    m_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, faceCandidates);
    int label = 0;
    for(const auto &face : faceCandidates) {
        cv::Mat faceResized;
        cv::resize(cv::Mat{frame, face}, faceResized,
                   cv::Size(this->m_size.width(), this->m_size.height()));

        faces.push_back(faceResized);
    }

    return faceCandidates.size();
}

bool Recognizer::train(const std::vector<qint32> &labels, const std::vector<QByteArray> &rgb888s)
{
    if (labels.empty() || rgb888s.empty() || labels.size() != rgb888s.size())
        return false;

    std::vector<cv::Mat> mats = {};
    std::vector<int32_t> processedLabels = {};
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for(const QByteArray &data : rgb888s)
    {
        std::size_t count = this->extractFacesAndConvertGrayscale(data, mats);
        if (count)
            std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(processedLabels), count, labels[i++]);
    }
    m_model->train(mats, processedLabels);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the size/aspect ratio of `faceCandidateRegion`?

Comment: just updated post. actually I've already tried resize with something like (... , 1.0, 1.0, cv::INTER_CUBIC); with the same wrong result

Comment: It's interesting that `model->predict(grayscale, label, confidence);` works fine. Did you crop the faces to train the classifier?

Comment: no, those ones prepared for the test in the same resolution in jpeg files

Comment: The multiscale detector will return a cropped square face. If you're training the classifier with the entire camera frame, with background and such, they won't work together. You should use detected faces to train the model.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot for the tip, but it's not my case for business requirements: I'm provided with pre-stored (in database blobs jpegs) and should pre-train a model on the app starting. does it mean that I have to additionally prepare the photos for model to cut off all of around the faces there? let me update a post

Comment: In this case, you should probably use `m_cascade` to detect the faces in the database images, then use those to train the model.

Comment: thank you so much! if you could reply as "answer" i'd mark your response as a solution to increase you rate )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolved this in the comments, but for future reference:

The fact that this line

```cpp
// this line for the testing purposes only
model->predict(grayscale, label, confidence);
```

had better confidence than

```cpp
// Recognize current face.
m_model->predict(faceResized, label, confidence);
```

occurred because the model was trained with non-cropped images, while the detector crops the faces.

Rather than using the whole image with prediction, to match the input, the model should be trained with cropped faces:

- The classifier performs independently of the size of the faces in the original image, due to the multiscale detection; i.e. size and position of the faces in the image become invariants.
- Background does not interfere with classification. The original input had 16:9 aspect ratio, so at least the sides of the image would produce noise in the descriptors.

Comment: is it important how to resize cv::Mats with cropped faces (for the train) ? "how" - I mean interpolation parameter of cv::resize(...) function?

Comment: I usually have no problem with the default (bilinear interpolation), as it's a fair balance between performance (nearest neighbors) and visual accuracy (bicubic). Though you can always test both cases and see if there's difference with your classifier choices.

Comment: seems it didn't solve my problem. now I have 5 cropped faces (of only one person)  from initial photos on the moment of training, however the prediction result (confidence) doesn't depend on existence testing face in training set or this is unknown face, the confidence very close to each other. in other hand - if I change the size of face cv::Mats for the training, the confidence is changing too: for 1000x1000 the confidence is about 9000, for 100x100 confidence is about 2500

Comment: Yes, the size affects the final "confidence". With `FisherFaceRecognizer`, it returns the L2 norm (distance) between the descriptors, which seem to be scaled on the input image size. So, you shouldn't use absolute values to compare, but relative to your system. Try training the model with 2 different sets of faces (or more), cropped with the same algorithm, then check the distance of faces that belong to the set, and faces that don't. The algorithm we generally use to determine the confidence threshold is a little different, but follows this idea.

Comment: just changed to Fisher, used two persons with 5 images for each one (as discussed - cropped with DetectMultiScale before training. and perform three tests: 1) first person's face from training set - distance=0, label=2(correct for my case); 2)second person's face from training set, the same distance=0 ,label=correct;3) second person's face NOT from training set; confidence=41655; INCORRECT label! (label refers to first person. code for prediction uses the same function to crop incoming photo. double checked this with another photos of second person, similar confidence and incorrect label...

Comment: updated initial post with a source of this method (you see - Qt is also in the use). it processes each photo from the database , as well as incoming photos for recognizing

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code (minor thing: if more than one face is detected, it probably has false positives. I'd use the biggest rectangle. But that shouldn't change the current results). You can always try other methods (I only named Fisher because of the OP, I usually go with LBPH) and different faces. These methods are not exact, and some prediction errors happen. You should evaluate the whole system to know how much they do, even with open face datasets. Then, if errors continue happening, I think you might want to open a new question, for more exposure/answers.